# the order of "hasNextInt()" and "nextInt()" method

Tags: java

I found that when I switch the order of "nextInt()" and "hasNextInt()",the result of my code will change, but I don't know why. How to explain the differences between writing `nextInt()` first and writing `hasNextInt()` first?

At the first time, I wrote `i=sc.nextInt()` before

```
while(!sc.hasNextInt()) {
    System.out.print("please input an integer");
    sc.next();
}
```

However, the code end up making me input two integers and that's not I want. 
Thus, I switch the order of `i=sc.nextInt()` and

```
while(!sc.hasNextInt()) {
    System.out.print("please input an integer");
    sc.next();
}
```

This time I only need to input one integer as my expectation.

```java
import java.util.*;

public class square {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while(true) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            int i;

            System.out.print("Input a number to calculate the square of it");
            i = sc.nextInt();
            while(!sc.hasNextInt()) {
                System.out.print("please input an integer");
                sc.next();
            }
            System.out.println("the square of"+i+"is"+i*i);
        } //while(true)
    }
}
```

If I write `i=sc.nextInt()` before

```
while(!sc.hasNextInt()) {
   System.out.print("please input an integer");
   sc.next();
}
```

the result of my code is the square of the first number I input. And I can't understand where is the second number I input and why I need to input integers twice.

But if I write

```
while(!sc.hasNextInt()) {
    System.out.print("please input an integer");
    sc.next();
}
```

before `i=sc.nextInt()`, the program will be executed correctly.

Comment: Check out the Scanner class as described in the java docs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should declare your `Scanner` once before your loop. As far as I can tell, the issue is your inner loop consuming non integer values; instead of looping like that, I would check that `if` there is an `int` before trying to consume it and use an `else` to consume anything else. Also, `System.out` is buffered; if you don't use `println()` (which has an *implicit* `flush`) you ***should*** `flush()`. Like,

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {
    System.out.println("Input a number to calculate the square of it");
    if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
        int i = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.printf("the square of %d is %d%n", i, i * i);
    } else {
        System.out.println("please input an integer");
        sc.next();
    }
} // while(true)
```